# How to Navigate to sections with id as well as pages in React Router Dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a Main page that contains 4 section ** #home, #collection, #products and #contact** and I have 2 different page for /cart and /login
*Navbar Code is Here*

```
`<nav>

            <div className='wrap-nav'>
                <NavLink href="" className='logo'>NILESTORE</NavLink>
                <div className='wrap-ul'>
                    <ul className='nav-links' >
                    
                        <li><NavLink to="#home">Home</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="#collection">Collection</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="#products">Products</NavLink></li>                
                        <li><NavLink to="#contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul className='nav-items'>
                    <li><NavLink to="/cart" className='cart' data-item={data.cartItems.length}><BsBag /></NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="/login" className='login'>Login</NavLink></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              
            </div>
        </nav>`
```

*App.js code is here*

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css"
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Cart from './pages/Cart';
import Main from './pages/Main';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
      <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
    </Routes>
    </Router>
    </>

  )
}

export default App
```

SO when I am in main page that works fine and I can reach that section when clicking the section like when i click on products i can reach on #products
After that when I click on **/cart** and **/login** page I  can reach on that page but myNavbar is same for all pages so when I click on Products, it doesn't work

I have tried all the possibilities on changing the NavLink like I have changed #products to /#products but also It doesn't work

Is there any solution for that

Comment: Hey Paw can you update full code of Navbar... Thanks

Comment: I don't know why you deleted your previous post and reposted the same question instead of just updating it the these new relevant details. To answer your question "I am using RRDV6, and how can I roll a custom solution?" means you'll need to read the hash from url paths you are navigating to in the target component and scroll those elements into view after the page/component mounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To navigate to a particular section of a particular page, you might want to use a HashLink in your Navbar component.

Installation:
`npm i react-router-hash-link`

Import it as:
`import { HashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';`

And use it as:

`<li><HashLink to={"/page#id"}>Contacts</HashLink></li>`

You can learn more about the same [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do one of these two:

First You can change your navbar and when you go to a page like a login page or cart page , your navbar doesn't show the other option till the user get back to the home page.

Second is that you pass a variable when you click on those (home, collection, products, and contact). you will say okay go to the home page if I am not at the home page then you will check the state and if there was one of these variables (home, collection, products, and contact) you can navigate to them by using js.

```
pathname: '/somewhere',
search: '?some=search-string',
hash: '#howdy',
state: {
[userDefined]: true
}
```

basically, this is what you find when you use location hook.

for more information check out the website

[react-router-dom "#location"](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location)